# how to Increment Data of the Same table with AutoIncrement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

how to Increment Data of the Same table with AutoIncrement .i have a table with 4 columns

```
id    type   no     amount
1     type1  a1      1000
2     type1  a2      2000
3     type2  b1      3000
4     type3  c1      4000
```

using Loop how can i increment them to hundered rows same data .

```
id    type   no     amount
1     type1  a1      1000
2     type1  a2      2000
3     type2  b1      3000
4     type3  c1      4000
5     type1  a1      1000
6     type1  a2      2000
7     type2  b1      3000
8     type3  c1      4000
9     type1  a1      1000
10     type1  a2      2000
11     type2  b1      3000
12     type3  c1      4000
```

Please suggest me the best using loop .How can i move forward on this one

Comment: I think the need is to 'duplicate' those records, but continue to increment them (in `id`). If this is the case AND the `id` column is already set up as IDENTITY - then you just have to loop through and insert them into the table.

Answer (score 1):

Use a table with sufficient number of rows in a cross join.

This will add the rows you already have in your table 100 times.

```
insert into YourTable(type, no, amount)
select type, no, amount
from YourTable
  cross join (
             select top(100) 1
             from sys.all_objects
             ) as T(X)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way of inserting part of your table into same table.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1
    SELECT TOP 4 type,no,amount
    FROM TABLE1
    ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: how can i  insert the 4 records into same table make it as 1 lakh records.

Comment: You can put it in a while loop or add 'GO 1000' at the end of the this statement to loop it.

Answer (score 0):

1. There are two ways in which you can achieve the requirement:

   1. If the insert statements are easy to script out and there are less records:

      ```
      USE <database_name>  
      Go  
      INSERT INTO looprecords([type],[no],[amount]) VALUES('type1','a1',1000);  
      INSERT INTO looprecords([type],[no],[amount]) VALUES('type1','a2',2000);  
      INSERT INTO looprecords([type],[no],[amount]) VALUES('type2','b1',3000);
      INSERT INTO looprecords([type],[no],[amount]) VALUES('type3','c1',4000);  
      Go 5            -- You can control this number on how many times you want to loop.
      ```
   2. If the insert statements cannot be scripted easily then:

      ```
      insert into looprecords([type],[no],[amount])
      select [type],[no],[amount] from looprecords;
      ```

Every time you run it it inserts records in this sequence 1,2,4,8,16,32........so on.
(For example if there are 16 records existing, in the next run it will give you 32 records)

Put the T-SQL in any valid loop to get the desired results.

I hope it has answered your question.